# Dynamically change XAML column text

Tags: c#, xaml

How do I programmatically set border XAML objects?

I can set it in the XAML:

```
<Border Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1">
     <TextBlock Text="Typical Code" />
</Border>
```

Here I have it with a name to set it:

```
<Border x:Name="Column8Text" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1">
</Border>
```

This has no effect:

```
Column8Text.Name = "test";
```

This is the entire grid im trying to dynamiclly manipulate:

```
  <StackPanel x:Name="GridViewView" >
                    <Grid x:Name="StaticGridView" Background="WhiteSmoke">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Column5" />
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Column6" />
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Column7" />
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Column8" />
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Column9" />
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Column10" />
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Column11" />
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Column12" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="Border">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
                            </Style>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="16" />
                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                            </Style>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
                            <TextBlock Text="Item" />
                        </Border>
                        <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
                            <TextBlock Text="Drawing" />
                        </Border>
                        <Border Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1">
                            <TextBlock Text="Typical Code" />
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="Column8Text" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1">
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="Column9Text" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1">
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="Column10Text" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="1">
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="Column11Text" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="1">
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="Column12Text" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="1">
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do... re-name a border element? Set the textBlock inside of it?

Comment: Set the textblock. When you say it that way it seems obvious now.

Comment: The answer you mean? Also, there is no textblock inside of it, so do you just need to dynamically create one and add it? Wouldn't just binding the text of an existing one be better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This has no effect:   `Column8Text.Name = "test"`;

To set any child object's values one cannot simply name the parent and have access to the children.

Each individual child control has to be named to be accessed in code behind.

Otherwise to change the child objects via a parent, one should create a custom control with specific dependency properties tied to the children underneath to facilitate the passage of data to the children.

---

To complete your example

```
<Border Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1">
     <TextBlock Name="tbBorderChild" Text="Typical Code" />
</Border>
```

Then access it in codebehind as such:

```
 tbBorderChild.Text = "Changed";
```